# Does React hook uses two way binding? if yes then does it hamper the perfomance compare to React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React hook uses function component and binds function at the time of state initilisation. I am confused how it is using two way binding. if we look into the two way binding of angular, there it is clearly visible.